# How to properly set nginx timeouts as proxy?

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-elb

I am getting a few 502 errors in nginx:

> 2020/05/05 20:40:05 [error] 13425#0: *1360447 recv() failed (104:
>   Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream,
>   client: 172.31.12.13, server: , request: "POST /app/functionHTTP/1.1",
>   upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/function", host: "example.com"

Architecture:

```
client - load balancer - instances (each with nginx proxy for NodeJS http server)
```

Timeout values:

- client:

  - request timeout: 60s
- load balancer:

  - keepalive timeout: 60s
- nginx:

  - http keepalive_timeout: 65s
  - upstream keepalive_timeout: 60s
  - upstream keepalive: 256 connections
  - proxy_connect_timeout: 60s
  - proxy_read_timeout: 60s
  - proxy_send_timeout: 60s
- server (NodeJS):

  - request timeout: 50s
  - keepAliveTimeout: 65s
  - headersTimeout: 70s

The 502 errors occur rarely (~0.01% of requests) but consistently.

What I've checked so far:

- Limit of file descriptors not reached
- Limit of nginx connections not reached
- Limit of TCP ports not reached
- Limit of CPU, memory, disk I/O not reached

It looks much like a race condition where the NodeJS server closed the connection and nginx is assuming the connection still exists.

What would be proper nginx timeout values in the current setting?

*(I am unsure whether this isn't rather a question for ServerFault?)*

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this as well